# javascript event handling

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I am building a web form for a login. I've decided to add in a few features I wouldn't normally. However I can't seem to get them to work in every instance. So, here's my problem.

On the form, as you progress through each of the inputs a javascript box on the side of the page scrolls down and notifies you about that input i.e. what they can enter, how many characters they have left.

It works great with text boxes, because i can use an onfocus and onblur event handler. However when you reach, for example, a div that has multiple check-boxes you can't exactly use the above event handlers for each input, because then they would have to select an option before the box tells them what it is about.

Ive tried using the onMouseOver and onMouseOut event handlers for the whole div, but it doesn't work fluidly.

So any suggestions? Maybe, is there a way to active a function if a users puts their cursor on a certain part of the screen?

hope this make sense,
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could make a little ? icon or something next to it for someone to hover over, and attach the event to that...

...anyways...you sure you doing it right? post some code...for example, this works just fine..when I hover over the 2nd checkbox, I get the alert

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
<input onmouseover="alert('test');" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car
</form>
```

Comment: I want the function to run when its over a div, which contains multiple inputs. For me, when i did it firebug told me that even when i was over the div and moving my mouse around it was still running the onMouseOut event handler.

Comment: Set DIVs for every textbox without setting the whole in one, and then set the onmouseover of that div.

Answer (score 0):

You should still have the focus/blur events on the checkboxes I think, for people using the keyboard.

Are you working with a js framework? With jQuery, you can simply do:

```
$(function() {
    $(".div_around_the_checkboxes").hover(function() {
        // show
    },
    function() {
        // hide
    });
});
```

Comment: what the difference between that an onMouseOver and onMouseOut event handler? because it still produces the same result when i try it.

Comment: It should be "the same", except using jquery might be more safe and consistent across browser, and has a nicer syntax. If you don't use any js framework and you have more than a few lines of js, you should consider using one. What do you mean by "doesnt work fluidly"? (I updated the code above)